# Recording Audio | Samson R31S Microphone | Volume too low

Tags: audio-recording, microphone

I am trying to setup a home recording studio. I recently purchased this Mic Samson R31S ( I know its not that good but i am just giving it a go). 
When i connect this Mic to the microphone-in port on my laptop and record. I get a very low volume wave when recording. Also the recorded track is mono and not stereo.
How do i fix this ? I don't have a mixer.
Is there something wrong with the mic or the cable.

Answer (score 2):

Your microphone is only a mono source, so if you want it into both channels you will need a plug which takes this mono signal and adapts it to stereo.

Generally laptop inputs are not the best for audio. Sure, there are some good ones, but generally you want a proper pre-amp with balanced inputs, which is why there is such a strong market in decent audio interfaces and external soundcards.

Without that, the input amplifier in your laptop just may not have sufficient gain.

Answer (score 0):

OK so your new... no biggie we all started some where.  First thing you need a board so you can handle the sound appropriately... your computer just won't ever be enough.... no matter what the argument...  proper pre Amp is every thing in sound.. get a board get obsessed and have fun.......... this is key

Comment: absolutes are unlikely to hold

Answer (score 0):

All live sound (ie bands) are mono... its up to the live sound engineer to blend what your hear into a cohesive cognitive algorithm of bliss that is what the masses deem as music.. but there is nothing wrong with the mic or cable.. single input single output 
Simple....

Comment: What about stereo effects?  What does a live sound engineer have to do with a home studio?  What do you know of the mic or cable to be able to say that there is nothing wrong with them?

Comment: I agree that this is a misleading answer. A single element microphone is mono, but stereo microphones exist. Claiming that "all live sound" is mono is vague and inaccurate.